# Get last message sent to channel

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I already have a variable containing a specific channel, but how can I obtain the last message sent to the channel? I want to make my bot only perform an action if the last message to the channel wasn't by it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you already have the specific channel stored in a variable, it's quite easy. You can call the `MessageManager#fetch()` method on that specific channel and get the latest message.

Example:

```
let channel // <-- your pre-filled channel variable

channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 1 }).then(messages => {
  let lastMessage = messages.first();
  
  if (!lastMessage.author.bot) {
    // The author of the last message wasn't a bot
  }
})
.catch(console.error);
```

However if you don't have the complete channel object saved in a variable but only the channel ID, you'll need to fetch the correct channel first by doing:

```
let channel = bot.channels.get("ID of the channel here");
```

Answer (score 7):

Recently I believe they've changed from `channel.fetchMessages()` to `channel.messages.fetch()`

```
channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 1 }).then(messages => {
  let lastMessage = messages.first();

  // do what you need with lastMessage below

})
.catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a property containing the object of the last writte message. So the most short version of getting last Message is:

```
let lm = channel.lastMessage;
```

Of course @Tyler 's version is still working. But my IDE says that he don't know `first()`. So may this will be deprecated some day?!? I don't know.

Anyway, in both ways you retrieve an object of the message. If you want to have e.g. the text you can do this

```
let msgText = lm.content; // channel.lastMessage.content works as well
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying to get the last message using this property `lastMessage`. But this property is null (while `lastMessageID` is not). Do I need to fetch something or something ?
For now I am getting channel using `const guildChannel: GuildChannel = guild.channels.cache.get(ID)`

Comment: have you tried Tylers fetching method? But to answere this i have to test on my own and debug result.