# How do I use message fetch in discord js?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

How can i make my discord js bot fetch messages from a channel and add them to an embed and send them in the channel.
I tried [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53696875/get-last-message-sent-to-channel#:~:text=You%20can%20call%20the%20MessageManager,and%20get%20the%20latest%20message.&text=There%20is%20a%20property%20containing,let%20lm%20%3D%20channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53696875/get-last-message-sent-to-channel#:%7E:text=You%20can%20call%20the%20MessageManager,and%20get%20the%20latest%20message.&text=There%20is%20a%20property%20containing,let%20lm%20%3D%20channel).
But it throws

```
channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 1 }).then(messages => {
                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetch' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/container/index.js:35:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
```

in the console.
Please help.

Comment: which discord.js version you are using. and what is your channel look like

Comment: `channel.messages` is `undefined`, what is stored in your `channel` variable? Please add output of `console.log(channel)`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I don't know what your `channel` variable is, but it should be a Discord.Channel

But to fetch a channel's messages like you seem to be trying to do, you firstly need to get a channel.
How to get a channel:

```
const channel_by_ID = client.channels.cache.get("CHANNEL-ID-HERE");
```

Then to fetch a message from it, you cant just add `.fetch()`, you need to request the `.cache`, so like this:

```
const channel = client.channels.cache.get("CHANNEL-ID-HERE");
const messageFetched = channel.messages.cache.fetch({ limit: 1 }).then(messages => {
     /* CODE HERE */
});
```

Hope this helps your issue, if not, I am extremely sorry. :<