# DiscordJS 13 user embed display last message sent in specific channel

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am building a profile slash command for discord.js 13. The command checks users roles and displays specific information about them. We are hoping to add the persons introduction from an introduction channel. Is there anyway to pull the last message sent from a user from a specific channel?

Current Code

```
        try{
        await guild.members.fetch();
        const member = guild.members.cache.get(UserOption.id);
        const roles = member.roles;
        const userFlags = UserOption.flags.toArray();
        const activity = UserOption.presence?.activities[0];
        //create the EMBED
        const embeduserinfo = new MessageEmbed()
        embeduserinfo.setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true, size: 512 }))
        embeduserinfo.setAuthor("Information about " + member.user.username + "#" + member.user.discriminator, member.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }), "https://discord.gg/FQGXbypRf8")
        embeduserinfo.addField('**❱ Username**',`<@${member.user.id}>\n\`${member.user.tag}\``,true)
        embeduserinfo.addField('**❱ Avatar**',`[\`Link to avatar\`](${member.user.displayAvatarURL({ format: "png" })})`,true)
        embeduserinfo.addField('**❱ Joined Discord**', "\`"+moment(member.user.createdTimestamp).format("DD/MM/YYYY") + "\`\n" + "`"+ moment(member.user.createdTimestamp).format("hh:mm:ss") + "\`",true)
        embeduserinfo.addField('**❱ Joined MetroVan**', "\`"+moment(member.joinedTimestamp).format("DD/MM/YYYY") + "\`\n" + "`"+ moment(member.joinedTimestamp).format("hh:mm:ss")+ "\`",true)            
        //DIRECT MESSAGE DISPLAY CODE
        if (roles.cache.find(r => r.id === "893305823315492914")) //dms are open
        {
            embeduserinfo.addField("**❱ DM STATUS**\n` OPEN` ", "** **", true)
        }
```

Comment: Where is your attempt? Do you have one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async function searchForLastMessageFromUser(channel, userId) {
let messages = await channel.messages.fetch({before: null}, {cache: true});
while (messages.size > 0) {
    let result = messages.find(message => {
        return message.author.id === userId;
    });
    if (result !== null) return result;
    messages = await channel.messages.fetch({limit: 50, before: messages[messages.length - 1]}, {cache: true});
}
return null;
```

}

```
embeduserinfo.setDescription("**❱ INTRODUCTION**\n" + introMessageText, "** Add your intro at <#885123781130067988>**");
```

Comment: the reason why this might break - what if the last message by the user was the last 51th message? it wont be read

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the last message in the channel, use the below code. Possible duplicate of [Get last message sent to channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53696875/get-last-message-sent-to-channel)

```
let channel = bot.channels.get('id-of-the-channel');
channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 1 }).then(messages => {
  let lastMessage = messages.first();
  
  if (!lastMessage.author.bot) {
    // Do something with it
  }
})
.catch(console.error);
```

If you want the last message sent in a channel by a specific user, filter it with the id property as below-

```
let channel = bot.channels.get('id-of-the-channel');
channel.messages.fetch().then(messages => {
  
  let lastMessage = messages.filter(m => m.author.id === 'id-of-user').last;
  //Do something with it
})
.catch(console.error);
```

Comment: implemented this code but am getting an error
`DiscordAPIError: Missing Access
    at RequestHandler.execute (/Users/server/Bot Deployed/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:298:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (/Users/server/Bot Deployed/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:50:14)
    at async MessageManager._fetchMany (/Users/server/Bot Deployed/node_modules/discord.js/src/managers/MessageManager.js:219:18) {
  method: 'get',
  path: '/channels/12456789/messages',
  code: 50001,`

Comment: Try giving your bot administrator perms

Comment: Will look into this later today and report back. Should work